Universal quantifiers in Lark grammar
I have been developing a Lark grammar to handle statements in the following format:
R is reflexive & S is reflexive -> R | S is reflexive
The current version assumes that all binary relations (R and S, in this example), along with the set A (on which the relations are defined), are provided by the user. The input looks like this:
A = {1,2,3}
R = BinaryRelation({(1,1)}, A, A)
S = BinaryRelation({(2,2),(3,3)}, A, A)

I want to extend the functionality so that the parser can handle universal quantifiers. The statements will have the following format:
∀R<AxA ∀S<AxA (R is reflexive & S is reflexive -> R | S is reflexive)
where the input will only be the set A, for example:
A = {1,2,3}
Here is my current version of Lark grammar:
Lark('''
    %import common.CNAME
    %import common.WS
    %ignore WS

    RELATION: CNAME
    QUANTIFIER: "\u2200"  // Unicode code point for ∀

    start: quantified_expression
         | logical_implication

    ?logical_implication: logical_and_or
                        | logical_implication "->" logical_and_or  -> implication

    ?logical_and_or: predicate
                   | logical_and_or "and" predicate  -> conjunction
                   | logical_and_or "or"  predicate  -> disjunction

    ?predicate: special_operator
              | predicate "="  special_operator  -> equal
              | predicate "!="  special_operator  -> not_equal
              | predicate ">"   special_operator  -> greater_than
              | predicate "<"   special_operator  -> lower_than
              | predicate ">="  special_operator  -> greater_equal
              | predicate "<="  special_operator  -> lower_equal

    ?special_operator: properties
                     | "not" predicate      -> negation
                     | expression "is" properties     -> is
                     | expression "is not" properties -> is_not

    ?properties: expression    
                | "total_order"   -> total_order
                | "transitive"    -> transitive
                | "reflexive"     -> reflexive
                | "symmetric"     -> symmetric
                | "asymmetric"    -> asymmetric
                | "antisymmetric" -> antisymmetric
                | "irreflexive"   -> irreflexive

    ?expression: literal
               | "\\i{" expression "}"  -> inverse
               | expression "\\o" literal   -> composition
               | expression "&" literal   -> intersection
               | expression "|" literal   -> union
               | expression "-" literal   -> difference
               | expression "^" literal   -> symmetric_difference
               | "\\c{" expression "}"  -> complement
               | "\\dom{" expression "}"   -> image
               | "\\preimage{" expression "}"   -> preimage

    ?literal: "("logical_implication")"
             | RELATION

    ?quantified_expression: (quantifier)* "(" logical_implication ")" -> universal_quantification
    quantifier: QUANTIFIER RELATION "<" RELATION "x" RELATION
''', start='start')

As you can see, I have the rule for handling quantifiers:
?quantified_expression: (quantifier)* "(" logical_implication ")" -> universal_quantification
This, however, won't handle the statement correctly. I'm always getting this error:
UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal matches '∀' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 8

∀R<AxA ∀S<AxA (R is reflexive and S is reflexiv
       ^
Expected one of: 
    * X

So the first quantifier is handled correctly, but anything that goes after the first quantifier causes an error (no matter if it's another quantifier or the implication). Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
